# su alias using expect returns some warning message. "expect: spawn id exp4 not open"

Tags: bash, alias, expect, su

I wrote "sul" alias which login other user using expect script.
After successful login with su alias "func_su()", every time I input "exit" command to go back to original user,
it shows this message. I'd like to remove this message. please teach me.

```
[23:21:02]$ exit
logout
expect: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"expect eof"
```

Alias "func_su()" command which I add .bashrc is the following.

```
func_su(){
    if [ "$1" == "" ];then account=master;else account=$1; fi
    echo account is [$account]

    expect -c "
    spawn su - ${account}
    expect {
        \"Password: \" { send \"!123456\r\" }
    }
    interact
    expect eof
    " }

alias sul="func_su master"
```

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: remove `expect eof` after `interact`.

Comment: @sexpect is right: once you `exit`, then spawned command ends and the interact commands returns. Then, when you hit "expect eof", there's no process to expect upon.

Comment: I solved the problem by comments from sexpect & glenn jackman. Thanks a lot. 
To close this question, do I have to upload answer by myself about this?